# hg-git repository not found

Tags: github, mercurial, hg-git

I would like to configure my Mercurial project to be able to push it into gitHub repository.

While using command:

> hg push git+ssh://git@github.com/myusername/myproject.git

I receive a msg:

> abort: repository git+ssh://git@github.com/myusername/myproject.git
>   not found!

I already check and establish SSH connection, and it looks ok:

> Hi myusername! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
>   provide shell access.

my respository url copied from github (it's a fork from other open-source project): https://github.com/myusername/myproject.git

What else I should check? Why I have an information that it doesn't exist while, in fact, it does? Where can be a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you have enabled and setup the hg-git extension correctly. This error also appears if the extension is not correctly setup.

Can you try it with a local git repository to phase-out github as a possible error.

Comment: That is possible that the setup is a problem. I am very new about mercurial. What do you mean by "phase-out github"? And how can I check hg-git setup?

Comment: create somewhere a temporary git repository (git init) and push to the local git repository.

Comment: If you get that error it means it isn't setup correctly. See http://hg-git.github.io/ under installation for instructions.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to rfkortekaas I found a problem with hg-git setup.

In ~/.hgrc there has to be:

> [extensions]
>
> hgext.bookmarks =
>
> hggit =

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can push in Git if you didn't clone your repository from a Git one before using hg-git. It seems me that hg-git manages a .git locally.

Comment: You mean I cannot use existing mercurial project? But only use hg-git pull from git-hub and then work? I'll try this, thanks.